# get BluetoothDevice Services android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Is there any method to get BluetoothDevice features list? ie) A bluetooth device is a device, system, printer or scanner, etc.. I want to get services from a particular device by BluetoothDevice. Is there is any intent to get the services of device?

Answer (score 1):

> BluetoothClass is useful as a hint to roughly describe a device (for example to show an icon in the UI), but does not reliably describe which Bluetooth profiles or services are actually supported by a device

To get supported services from the device, we have to use

```
android.bluetooth.BluetoothClass.Service
```